# throw "Unknown command: jmeter" when execute the testcased in jmeter GUI model

Tags: jmeter

As the screenshot shows, it will throw an error when I try to execute tcs in GUI model in Jmeter

[image: 1]

Comment: Is the `jmeter` launcher located in subdirectory `D/C/a/bin` ? Or is it on your `PATH` [environment] variable? You are on a MacBook computer, right?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to be able to run `jmeter` command from any directory it must be in your operating system [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))
2. If `jmeter` shell script is present in `D/C/a/bin` directory you need to call it as `./jmeter` instead
3. It's better to use [`jmeter.sh`](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.5/bin/jmeter.sh) instead of `jmeter` as it reads Java command line arguments overrides if any and checks for presence/correctness of Java runtime installation

More information: [JMeter Installation: How to Get Started](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-installation)